# angle brackets after struct

Tags: c++, struct, class-template

I have problems with understanding the following line in a C++ Code:

```
template<class Variable> struct strVar< :: namespaceName::strVar2_<Variable>> : public trueType {};
```

What does the angle brackets after struct strVar mean? I never heard of this style before.

The line does not compile with my compiler, but it comes from a running software, so it must be right in some sense.

Comment: It's a partial specialisation of the class template `strVar`. This should be covered in any [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Could be a template specialization, though I don't know how this one would work really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code defines a partial specialisation of class template `strVar`. Somewhere earlier in the code, there must be at least a declaration of the primary template:

```
template <class T> struct strVar;
```

Then, the code you posted provides a definition which will be used for `strVar` whenever its template argument (corresponding to `T`) happens to be a specialisation of the class template `::namespaceName::strVar2_`.

Example:

```
strVar<int> x;  // will use primary template
strVar<::namespaceName::strVar2_<int>> x;  // will use the specialisation
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will try to figure it out...maybe I forgot including some other headers. I never heard of partial specialisation of a struct, but you are right it must be that way